# How to convert image from png to jpg in jimp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image

I read the docs: https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp

But could not find how to convert an image from png to jpg.

I must have missed something obvious.

Using jimp on my server with Node.js.

Here's my code:

```
image.scaleToFit(500, 500, Jimp.RESIZE_BICUBIC).quality(60).write("./public/images/uploads/thumb"+req.file.filename, function(err) {
```

Comment: Have you tried loading the image and saving it as a different format?

Comment: What is "req.file.filename" ? Appears that you are trying to save with the original filename, and from what you said it sounds like original filename is "png" therefore you get output "png". Try adding ".jpg" extension

Comment: @EdgarZagórski That was it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is wrong with the example from their documentation? It kind of does what you want - converts png to jpg.

```
var Jimp = require("jimp");

// open a file called "lenna.png"
Jimp.read("lenna.png", function (err, lenna) {
    if (err) throw err;
    lenna.resize(256, 256)            // resize
         .quality(60)                 // set JPEG quality
         .greyscale()                 // set greyscale
         .write("lena-small-bw.jpg"); // save
});
```

Comment: Added comment to your question :)